Action of $\text{SL}_3$ on the space of conics
We work over the complex numbers. Let $C$ be a conic in $\mathbb{P}^2$, which can be described as
$$C=\{x\in \mathbb{P}^2\mid x^T M_C x =0 \},$$
with $M_C$ a symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix. I know that the group $\text{SL}_3$ acts on $\mathbb{P}^2$, and I have know that the space of conics can be seen as $\mathbb{P}^5$ (you map the entries $a_{ij}$, for $i\geq j$).
Questions:

I have read that $\text{SL}_3$ acts on the space of conics, that is $\mathbb{P}^5$, but I don't see explicitly how;

with such an action, what is the stabilizer of the action on a conic?


My approach:
Take $A\in \text{SL}_3$. Then I could consider the set $\{x\in \mathbb{P}^2\mid (Ax)^T M_C (Ax) =0 \},$ which is equal to
$$\{x\in \mathbb{P}^2\mid x^T (A^TM_CA) x =0 \}.$$
Is the action of $\text{SL}_3$ on the space of conics this one?
If so, the stabilizer of the conic should correspond to
$\{A\in \text{SL}_3 \mid A^TM_CA = M_C \}$, that is $\text{SO}_3$.
But I don't know if my approach is correct, and usually books I consulted just state this.

Yes, this is correct.

Instead od $SO(3)$ you should write $SO(q)$ where $q$ is the quadratic form defined by the symmetric matrix $M$. If $M$ is non degenerated this is $SO(3,C)$ but the quadratic form can be degenerate. In fact you have 3 orbits corresponding to the 3 quadratic forms (over $C$). $x^2+y^2+z^2, x^2+y^2, x^2$, and three different stabilizers. For instance the stabilizer of $z^2$ is the same as the stabilizer of the hyperplane $z=0$, or the affine group of the plane.
